# Deadlock with synchronized and scala futures

Tags: scala, asynchronous

I can't seem to figure out why the following code deadlocks:

```
"Locks around blocking futures" should "be re-entrant" in {
    val lock = new Object()

    def processInFuture = {
      lock.synchronized {
        // simulate async call made blocking
        Await.result(Future {
          blocking {
            logger.info("Sleeping")
            Thread.sleep(100)
            logger.info("Waking")
          }
        }, Duration.Inf)
      }
    }

    // fire off 10 async events and wait on each one
    (0 until 10).
      map(_ => Future { processInFuture }).
      foreach(future => Await.result(future, Duration.Inf))
  }
```

I can't see why making an async into sync in a critical section causes the whole fork-join pool to bork.

If I make the future execute on a separate pool from the fork join pool then it works.  I don't understand why the fork join pool thread doesn't block the other threads and then finish first?  Is it because the pool is somehow blocked?

I realize its always best to make everything async if its async, but some scenarios don't allow for that (for example cache population with a guava cache)

-- EDIT

To illustrate @Dima's answer this works

```
"Locks around blocking futures" should "be re-entrant" in {
    val lock = new Object()

    def processInFuture = {
      blocking { 
        lock.synchronized {
          // simulate async call made blocking
          Await.result(Future {
            blocking {
              logger.info("Sleeping")
              Thread.sleep(100)
              logger.info("Waking")
            }
          }, Duration.Inf)
        }
      }
    }

    // fire off 10 async events and wait on each one
    (0 until 10).
      map(_ => Future { processInFuture }).
      foreach(future => Await.result(future, Duration.Inf))
  }
```

Comment: If this is a common patter, whatever code you've been writing/looking at is way wrong. What logging framework are you using?

Comment: Aside from the question as to why this example deadlocks, perhaps you should explain what you really want to do as this example would generally be considered pathological. There are solutions that exist (e.g. akka) which are much better suited to protecting shared mutable state while working with async constructs like Futures. I actually can't imagine a good reason to mix locks with Futures unless the lock was in code you didn't have access to.

Comment: I ran into a scenario where a client I don't own basically does this and I need to protect that synchronous call from other async calls as its part of a lazy cache.  I would've assumed its safe to make an async call into a sync call and treat it as such within a critical section, whether thats a good idea or not

Comment: Wouldn't `Future{lock.synchronized{...}}` be more appropriate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The maximum number of threads in the default pool is equal to a number of cores you have. Say, 8. Here is what happens.

The first thread enters the critical section and starts sleeping (occupying another thread). Six more threads are started and pile up at the entrance of synchronized block. (There are still three more calls to start, but there are no threads available at the moment, so they are waiting).

The sleeping thread wakes up, satisfies that future, and the first thread exits synchronized block and finishes. The two threads are returned to the pool, so two more futures are immediately started.

One of the threads waiting for the lock wakes up and enters critical section.

Now, there are no threads available in the pool: 7 threads are waiting for the lock, and one is inside the critical section, for the total of 8.

The active thread tries to submit the Future, that will sleep, but gets blocked, because no more threads are available in the pool.

Now, 7 threads a waiting for the lock to be released, and the one holding the lock is waiting for another thread to become available.

--> Deadlock.

***Update*** Forgot to mention this: the way to fix it is to put `blocking` around the `processInFuture` call. That will let the pool realize it needs to go beyond the limit on threads.

Comment: @devshorts See the update I just added to the answer. You might find it helpful ...

Comment: that is incredibly helpful. I didn't realize you can put a blocking around a not future, and a synchronous block!

Comment: Great explanation, I would just add that it's not a good idea to use locking with Scala Futures, it's highly recommended to implement everything in an asynchronous way

Comment: @devshorts you should put `blocking` _inside_ the `Future`, not "around".

Comment: Actually I already had that and it still failed. When I put it around the future it worked. I assume it's because it submitted the future into a different pool, vs submitting the future to the same pool then running the blocking code in another pool

Comment: @devshorts This: `map(_ => Future { blocking { processInFuture } })` works for me ...